# Xcode Swift: Why is it breaking my Constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

I'm just learning Swift with the Start [Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html) Tutorial. I'm creating this custom Rating Control but every time i run the App is sends following Error:

```
2017-08-09 15:49:41.894597+0200 FoodTracker[5051:2273797] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409af90 UIButton:0x100c12d90.width == 44   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009c160 'UISV-canvas-connection' FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x100c02400.leading == UIButton:0x100c12d90.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009c200 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[UIButton:0x100c12d90]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x100c02400 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009bee0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x100c02400.width == 343   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409af90 UIButton:0x100c12d90.width == 44   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-08-09 15:49:41.895770+0200 FoodTracker[5051:2273797] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409af40 UIButton:0x100c12d90.height == 44   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009c250 'UISV-canvas-connection' FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x100c02400.top == UIButton:0x100c12d90.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009c340 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIButton:0x100c12d90]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x100c02400 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009bf30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' FoodTracker.RatingControl:0x100c02400.height == 50   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409af40 UIButton:0x100c12d90.height == 44   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I set the constraints for Button width == 44 and for Button height == 44, but none of the other constraints. I did everything as described in the Tutorial and have no clue why it doesn't work. I Checked all Constraints i can find but i'm not sure if it were all as I'm not very experienced with Xcode. Do anyone have a clue how to solve the Problem?

> This is how it should look like: [image: Apples Result] But this is how it looks:[image: My Result] (Only The Red Area is important)

Comment: Is the red square / rectangle a UIButton or a UIView?

Comment: UIButton inside of  a StackView.

Comment: ah - ok, I just took a look through the tutorial you're following.... Is the StackView itself inside a *vertical* StackView that holds the other elements? If so, is *that* StackView's `Alignment` set to `Fill`?

Comment: No, the Stack View is not inside of another Stack View.. Should it be?

Comment: But the Alignment of the horizontall Stack View is Fill

Comment: Yes... the tutorial tells you *"In your storyboard, use the Object library to find a Horizontal Stack View object, and drag one into your storyboard scene so that it’s in the stack view below the image view."*

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I also faced similar issue. The solution is simple, as shown, move (drag and drop) horizontal stack view under the vertical stack view as shown.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, I think you have embedded the button inside a `UIStackView`. The stack view has incorrect constraints, or no constraints at all and is using the autoresizing mask. The stack view is being given a size of 343x50 and is forcing the button to match.

Comment: All your suggestions are right. I dont set any Constraints for the Stack View. But the guys who wrote the Tutorial didnt either..(Aud they're from apple so it should be right i thought..) What do i have to do to unbind the Button to the size of the stacked view? Just set own constraints for the stack View?

Comment: Do you need a stack view at all?

Comment: There will come 5 Buttons that should be positioned next to each other (Horizontally). So i gues i need it? I dont really know, I want to learn it :D

Comment: Still i dont really want to work arozund the stack view as it is shown in the Tutorial and i want to learn how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a UIStackView. Remove the UIButton out of the UIStackView and set that UIButton's top constraint the same spacing you defined in your UIStackView and set the UIButton's align leading edge to the UiStackView and you're good

Comment: Ok, but i dont wnat to move the button out of the Stack View. The Tutorial should learn me how to work with stack views so i dont want to work arround them..

Comment: You should read about what a UIStackView's purpose is. Personally, I use it if I want identical constraints in all the views within it. You clearly don't want the same constraints for the UIButton. So it should be outside of the UIStackView. Taking it out won't make you learn less about UIStackView

Comment: I dont want the same Constrants for this Button as for the Stack View, but there will be 5 Buttons in this stack View which should have all the same constraints and lay next to each other (horizontaly).. I thought thts the purpose of a Stack View. To have multiple objects next to each other..

Answer (score 0):

I have found reason and solution.

Horizontal Stack View - filling whole own internal space by vertical and horizontal. It's mean - Horizontal Stack View will set height and wight for internal items to Fill all available space.

Only way to remove such warning which i found - is set width/height of Horizontal Stack View to fit perfectly with/height of all internal elements: 252x44